# Using autotools with a fresh Debian install

Tags: debian, autotools

ALL,

I just installed a fresh copy of Debian in order to test my software under this distro.

I installed and configured Git, installed build-essentials package, installed all necessary dependencies and cloned the code.

My main development machine is running Gentoo and my project is using Autotools.

In order to regenerate the configure + makefile I googled and found [this tutorial](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install).

However when I tried to run aclocal, I got `Command not found`.

I then tried to install `autotools-dev`, but that didn't fix it - I still receive the same error after running `aclocal`.

What package do I need to install? Is autotools-dev not enough? Should I even have this package?

I'm not really familiar with Debian distro, so hoping someone will help.

TIA!!

EDIT:

Moreover, the project was made on Gentoo with Anjuta in 2015 and so all those files needs to be regenerated anyway.

Comment: I have no idea why anyone these days would recommend running `aclocal` (or `autoconf` or `automake` or ...) *directly*.  Almost always, one ought to run `autoreconf`, and let it identify and run the needed individual tools, in the right order.  If you are upgrading to a new version of the autotools (and you probably are) then the correct incantation is `autoreconf --install --force`.

Comment: A look at the Debian package lists suggests that no, autotools-dev may not be enough.  There are separate packages for autoconf, automake, and libtool (and some old versions thereof), and I don't immediately see a metapackage that aggregates those.  The description of autotools-dev does not lead me to take it for such a package.